# Javascript not recognized a variable within a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script which can toggle images on and off by clicking a link for practice. I'm trying to select a "data-" attribute but when i try to define it to a variable it doesnt recognize it. It gives me the null error.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a data-img="image1" id="ugur1" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image one</a>
<a data-img="image2" id="ugur2" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image two</a>
<a data-img="image3" id="ugur3" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image three</a>

<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image1.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="ugurpic1" alt="Responsive image" />
<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image2.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="ugurpic2" />
<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image3.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="ugurpic3" />
```

Here is my JS:

```
var ugur1 = document.getElementById("ugur1");
var ugur2 = document.getElementById("ugur2");
var ugur3 = document.getElementById("ugur3");

ugur1.addEventListener("click", picLink);
ugur2.addEventListener("click", picLink);
ugur3.addEventListener("click", picLink);

function picLink() {
    var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
    var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
    if (pic.className === "img-responsive img hide") {
        pic.className = "img-responsive img";
    }
    else {
        pic.className = "img-responsive img hide";
    };
}
```

Can someone please show me what i'm doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: Try using document.getElementById("ugurpic1") instead of document.getElementById("ugur1") ?

Comment: And maybe adding some actual data attributes ?

Comment: If you check this https://jsfiddle.net/278rwmp7/1/, you can see that you don't have any `data-img` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting each `a` properly with `getElementById`, and adding the event listener properly. The problem is, when you select the `data-img` attributes, they don't contain the ids of the images. Basically, on each change `data-img="imageX"` to `data-img="ugurpicX"` to properly reflect the ids of the image tags, or change the ids of the image tags.

---

**Either**

```
<a data-img="ugurpic1" id="ugur1" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image one</a>
<a data-img="ugurpic2" id="ugur2" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image two</a>
<a data-img="ugurpic3" id="ugur3" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Toggle Image three</a>
```

**Or** (not both):

```
<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image1.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="image1" alt="Responsive image" />
<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image2.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="image2" />
<img src="C:\Users\Ugur Aydin\Desktop\Coding\Javascript\Images\Image3.png" class="img-responsive img hide" id="image3" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! also i've learned from this! So i understand that the id given to the data attribute must be the same as the id given to the image i'm trying to manipulate. Again, thank you!